# Play Audio in Phonegap isn´t working

Tags: audio, cordova

I don´t know why my function isn´t working in phonegap.. i´ve got the following:

```
     function Playsound() {

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("sound.mp3");
    }
    }
```

The Playsound() function is called, when clicking on a button. I want to play the sound then.

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    function onDeviceReady(){
    var snd2 = new Media("/android_asset/www/trink.mp3");
    snd2.play();
    }
```

doesn´t work either..

what´s wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phonegap build, you should include plugin in your *config.xml* file.

```
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.device"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```